# htaccess setting on Codeigniter V2

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Hi i'm using Codeigniter V2 and try to rewrite url

So i have done this steps :

I have htaccess file with following code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^asset.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^upload.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

And at config file i change config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

This my link website
http://www.beacukaitarakan.com/berita/berita.html

from active url 
http://www.beacukaitarakan.com/index.php/berita/berita.html

but with those htaccess file, http://www.beacukaitarakan.com/berita/berita.html will not go to http://www.beacukaitarakan.com/index.php/berita/berita.html but always showing homepage

It can be work if i use QUERY STRING instead of config uri protocol but i have some setting eg. navigation that use this setting
http://www.beacukaitarakan.com/berita/berita.html?**p=true&start=1**
so i need to use path info rather than QUERY STRING

thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

simply copy and paste the below code in the .htacces file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

for more read this http://w3code.in/2015/09/how-to-remove-index-php-file-from-codeigniter-url/